# How to have collapsing tabs under a CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a screen that is set up like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <AppBarLayout>

        <CollapsingToolbarLayout/>

            <RelativeLayout />

            <Toolbar/>

        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <TabLayout/>

    </AppBarLayout>

    <ViewPager/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm try to achieve an effect where once the collapsing toolbar is totally collapsed (with the toolbar pinned), then the tabs will scroll behind the toolbar.  I also want the tabs to scroll back in as soon as you start scrolling back up (like the enterAlways flag).

I've tried many implementations of this and haven't found one that does quite what I need, so any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

To try to clarify: when you open this screen the collapsing toolbar is fully expanded with tabs under it.  One you start scrolling, the collapsing toolbar starts to disappear with a parallax effect (I have already achieved this), and the tabs stay stuck to the bottom of the collapsing toolbar, and fully visible.  Once the toolbar is fully collapsed, if you keep scrolling, the tabs will scroll behind the toolbar also, and stay off screen as you keep scrolling, but as soon as you start scrolling back up, they should come back into the screen (as if they had the enterAlways scroll flag applied)

Comment: It'd be great if you could share a few images or a small video to explain what you exactly want. Thanks

Comment: I actually can't do that, as the application is proprietary.  I will edit the post to clarify

Comment: If possible, please post a small video with mock of what you want, you don't have to use the original app :)